# Difference between Flex and Flash pro in developing Mobile application

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

I am trying to learn how to develop an application on Android with flash. It seems to me that both Flex and Flash Pro CS6 can do it. So what are the difference between the two?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex is (in essence) a large ActionScript 3 library for building Rich Internet Applications (although you can use it for anything you like, such as games). Flex provides a range of styleable and extendable components that are much better than the ones you get in Flash Pro, plus a lot more - far too much to list here.

To use Flex properly, you need some ActionScript 3 knowledge - most things are done with code and there is no timeline.

Flex applications are usually 'code heavy' and created using Flash Builder (or other similar IDEs) as Flash Pro has poor coding features and is unsuitable (imho) for larger projects.